# Screen gets stuck in sencha touch select field change listener

Tags: android, iphone, sencha-touch, extjs

I have an strange problem with sencha touch. **Changing the value in the select field stuck the screen.** I have an application, where there are Select fields, And on change of select field value I am applying some rules. Rule is to remove all the screen elements and add it freshly.

**Below is the code snapshot.**

Now, **It is working absolutely fine with the chrome, safari browser and the iPad device browser. But now it is giving strange problem in iPhone and Android device**. The screen gets stuck. No events are allowed after changing the value in select field.

Steps Taken; Also, I have put alert as logger at each step of the source code to ensure the infinite loop. I have also put the exception handlers to ensure the error occurred. No errors, neither ant infinite loop running which might cause memory/run-time issue.

```
    App.views.MySampleScreen = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
        initComponent : function() {
            var titlebar = {
                dock : 'top',
                xtype : 'toolbar',
                cls: 'x-panel-title',
                title : "Home Screen"       
            };

           var  buttonbar = {
                xtype : 'toolbar',
                dock : 'bottom',
                cls: 'x-panel-footer',
                items : [
                    {xtype : "spacer"}                
                ]
            };


            var myFieldSet = new Ext.form.FieldSet({
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                id : 'myFieldSet',
                name: 'myFieldSet'

            });

           var formBase = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
                ui: 'round',
                id: 'standardFormBase',
                items: [myFieldSet],
            });

            Ext.apply(this, {
                scroll: 'vertical',
                pinHeaders: true,
                dockedItems : [titlebar, buttonbar],
                items : [formBase],

                listeners: {
                    beforeactivate: function(panel) {
                        createAndInitScreen();
                    }
                   }
            });

            App.views.MySampleScreen.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
        }   

    });

    Ext.reg('App.views.MySampleScreen', App.views.MySampleScreen);

    function createAndInitScreen(){

        var myFieldSet = Ext.getCmp("myFieldSet");
        myFieldSet.removeAll(true);

         var stateList2 = new Ext.form.Select({
            label: 'State',
            name: 'state',
            id: 'stateLis2t',
            widht: '100%',
            autoLoad: true,
            labelWidth: '40%',
           options: [{
                            text: 'Test', value: 'Test'
                        }, {
                            text: 'Test2', value: 'Test2'
                        }, {
                            text: 'Test3', value: 'Test3'
                        }],
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function(ele) {

                },
                change: function(field, value) {
                    createAndInitScreen(); // Here is the problem
                        // if i remove this then this works, but my need 
                        //is to call CreateAndInitScreen after value change in select ()
                }            
            }
        });

        myFieldSet.items.add(stateList2);

        myFieldSet.show();
        myFieldSet.doLayout();     
}
```

Comment: Try removing the id property of the stateList2. You are creating more the one `Ext.form.Select` object with same id. That could cause strange problems...

Comment: @ilija139 i have removed the Id property from Ext.form.Select. But still the problem exist.

Comment: Then I don't know. You should change the whole code. If you want to change the items in the `form.Select` then you need to remove the items and add new ones, not remove the whole object and then create a new one. The code is not well structured and you are probably running out of memory or something similar, or some infinitive loop (event or recursive).

Comment: @ilija139.. I highly appreciate your quick reply. Even i thought of changing the entire business logic. I was worried as it was working as expected in ipad device and also in safari/chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue with a work around. Instead of creating the control for each time, i am removing and adding the data from the screen elements. Thant works fine for my requirements. Anyways thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found the bug.

The selectfield cannot figure out the height of the screen on the iPhone.

On the iPad the height is calculated so the selectfield picker shows and the rest of the screen is masked till you dismiss the picker.

On the iPhone the picker is actually created and painted on the screen, its just not visible since the screen is assumed to be much bigger. ie the Picker is lower down on the screen (in the non visible part. It feels the screen is stuck/stalled because the masking still occurs.

If you decrease the height of the concerned panel (taking into account the iPhone screen height), you should have everything working perfectly.

Hope this helps someone. God knows I spend enough time on finding it ! :)